# What is Character B doing to Character A?

Tags: meaning, phrases, expressions

Character **C** was unfortunate to get infected with West Nile virus and now has wide rashes all over her body and has turned into an ugly looking woman(she was really hot before) and now faces the judgement and laughs of the society. She wants to seek a solution to this daily problem and hence, posts it on a forum where she writes her problem, asking self-proclaimed unattractive girls of forum about how they manage with these everyday problems?

I will write a dialogue piece between 2 people, **A**, an ugly woman, and **B**, a man, talking over the issues of Character C and apparently trying to sort it out.

> **A**: *So you want ugly girls to advise you? You are really fucked up.*
>
> **B** (to **A**): *No, I think she meant to seek advise from people who share the same problem and is seeking comfort(or sympathy), not trying to demean ugly girls like you.*

It seems that A has taken offense to what C has written (probably because of the awkward use of words on the part of C).

Here, B comes to support C and instead has intentionally/unintentionally ruffled A's feathers by passing an offhanded comment. He seems to support C but is being plain insensitive to A who is not wrong to get offended on her part. Also the audience viewing this comment will find it humorous.

What would this act of B be labelled? Could anyone explain this scenario?

Comment: So far as I can tell, character A (who btw you should label the woman) is not doing *anything at all* to character B (who you should label the man). A is addressing C; she doesn't even mention B.

Comment: Sorry, It's actually B. My mistake.

Comment: You forgot to change the title. Cleaned that up for you. Anyway, the humorous aspect of B's statement seems to be some form of [apophasis](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apophasis), or maybe even proslepsis.